# how Can I use Injector (Angular) into String or enum

Tags: angular

This case below does not work for String and Enum. What is the correct way. This is to reduce the number of parameters in the constructor. I have 10 parameters... The Sonarqube complains

```
 public nome?: string;
 public situacao?: SituacaoPadraoEnum;

  constructor(injector:Injector     
    ) {
        super();
        this.nome = injector.get<String>(String);
        this.SituacaoPadraoEnum = injector.get<SituacaoPadraoEnum>(SituacaoPadraoEnum);
    }
```

Thanks for help

Comment: "Sonarqube complains" about having 10 parameters. It doesn't say you have to inject all your parameters. Just the ones that make sense to inject (services and the like). Pass primitives alone, or if it continues to complain, as properties of an object (which again, you do not have to inject).

Comment: Even so, I still have a lot of parameters, Sonar only accepts up to 7.

Comment: ... and, if you read my comment again, you'd find you'd need at most two; the injector, and an object whose properties are the primitive values (which you could then deconstruct to your fields). `constructor(injector: Injector, args: { nome?: string, situacao?: SituacaoPadraoEnum }) { super(); const { nome, situacao } = args; }`

Comment: I found this way on the internet. ==>  injector.get<string>(<any>'nome');

Answer (score 0):

I found this way on the internet.  ==> injector.get('nome');

Does using the Injector bring any performance to the application? I'm just looking for change because of Sonar.

```
 public nome?: string;
    public numeroDocumento?: string;
    public numeroTelefone?: string;
    public idKeycloak?: string;
    public tipoPessoa?: TIPO_PESSOA;
    public dataNascimento?: string;
    public situacao?: SituacaoPadraoEnum;
    public endereco?: Endereco;
    public pais?: Pais;
    public email?: Email;

    constructor(injector? : Injector) {    
        super();
        this.nome = injector.get<string>(<any>'nome');
        this.numeroDocumento = injector.get<string>(<any>'numeroDocumento');
        this.numeroTelefone = injector.get<string>(<any>'numeroTelefone');
        this.idKeycloak = injector.get<string>(<any>'idKeycloak');
        this.tipoPessoa = injector.get<TIPO_PESSOA>(<any>'tipoPessoa');
        this.dataNascimento = injector.get<string>(<any>'dataNascimento');
        this.situacao = injector.get<SituacaoPadraoEnum>(<any>'situacao');
        this.endereco = injector.get<Endereco>(Endereco);
        this.pais = injector.get<Pais>(Pais);
        this.email = injector.get<Email>(Email);
    }
```